# try to extract data from string in structured format

Tags: php, parsing

I'm trying to parse some data in PHP, but I'm not entirely sure what the data format is. It appears to be a variant of JSON, but I'm not sure.

Here's an example;

```
    "kFj394"
{
        "allow"
        {
        }
        "name"  "Bob"
        "deny"
        {
        }
        "group" "trusted"
}
"J883Dd"
{
        "name"  "Foo Bar"
        "deny"
        {
        }
        "allow"
        {
        }
        "group" "regular"
}
```

I'm trying to get the nickname and group of the person from their ID (`kFj394` and `J883Dd` in this example)

If anyone knows how I could accomplish this, or even what data format this is, I'd appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure but it looks like json.

Comment: That is not at all json. You could use regular expressions to get this data, but it will not be simple. This data does not correspond to any standard at all.

Comment: where did the data it come from? Is this the original state of the data ?

Comment: It could be [Candle markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candle_%28programming_language%29)

Comment: It's a file on a game server representing the rank of each person. I've obscured the nickname and the ID to remove personal information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your format is there. It's definitely not JSON. Regular expression is probably your only shot:

```
$block = ''; // The text you pasted goes here.

foreach (['kFj394', 'J883Dd'] as $id) {
    $nameSearchPattern = '/"' . $id . '"[\n\t\s\w{}"]*?name"\s+"(.+)"/';
    $groupSearchPattern = '/"' . $id . '"[\n\t\s\w{}"]*?group"\s+"(.+)"/';
    preg_match($nameSearchPattern, $block, $nameMatches);
    preg_match($groupSearchPattern, $block, $groupMatches);
    $name = $nameMatches[1];
    $group = $groupMatches[1];
    echo "The name for $id is $name\n";
    echo "The group for $id is $group\n";
}
```

Comment: So you magically guess the ID's he's trying to get from the data and loop over them?

Comment: From the phrasing of the question, it sounded like the IDs were a given:

"I'm trying to get the nickname and group of the person from their ID (kFj394 and J883Dd in this example)"

Comment: Yeah, I have the ID and want the rank and nickname. Thanks for the code, @joehart worked perfectly :)